# Merge Two PHP Arrays into Multidimensional Array in Quadruped Jumps

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have two arrays that I want to merge in a distinct way. Suppose I have the following arrays:

```
$q_id = array(0 => 7, 1 => 8, 2 => 9)
$a_id = array(
      0 => 24, 
      1 => 25, 
      2 => 26, 
      3 => 27, 
      4 => 28,
      5 => 29, 
      6 => 30, 
      7 => 31, 
      8 => 32, 
      9 => 33,
      10 => 34, 
      11 => 35,
```

)

The end result I'm aiming at is:

```
array(

      [7] => array
        (
          [0] => 24
          [1] => 25
          [2] => 26
          [3] => 27
        )
      [8] => array
        (
          [4] => 28
          [5] => 29
          [6] => 30
          [7] => 31
        )
      [9] => array
        (
          [8] => 32
          [9] => 33
          [10] => 34
          [11] => 35
        )
)
```

The built-in functions of array manipulation do not meet my needs. A recursive merge code taken from a post made here on stackoverflow: [Combine arrays to form multidimensional array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301378/combine-arrays-to-form-multidimensional-array-in-php), creates an array in which each of the three keys that perform as subarrays receives only the first value of each group of fours:

```
     array(

      [7] => array
        (
          [0] => 24
        )
      [8] => array
        (
          [4] => 28
        )
      [9] => array
        (
          [8] => 32
        )
```

I'm positive the solution lies in recursivity (perhaps modifying the code snippet provided in the link above) but I just don't know how to go about it.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: And where is the code? Have you tried something?

Comment: The code appears in the link I provided. I tried to modify the code but result would only grab the first or last value of each group of fours. I mentioned that I tried using built-in functions (array_merge, array_merge_recursive, array_map etc,) that didn't prove as useful for this case.

Comment: @Daan I spent the entire day online and here on stack to find an solution for my problem. When all else fails, ask others. Nobody asked you to write any code for me, if you have anything useful to say then say it otherwise don't.

Comment: If you did research then show it here, add what you have found and tried and if it worked, helped you or if it was completely useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) the `$q_id` array as keys with the `$a_id` array as values. Where I use X chunks of the size `count($a_id)/count($q_id)` with [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) for the value arrays)

```
<?php

    $q_id = [7, 8, 9];
    $a_id = [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,];

    $result = array_combine($q_id, array_chunk($a_id, count($a_id)/count($q_id), TRUE));
    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24
            [1] => 25
            [2] => 26
            [3] => 27
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [4] => 28
            [5] => 29
            [6] => 30
            [7] => 31
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [8] => 32
            [9] => 33
            [10] => 34
            [11] => 35
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this. On a side note, could you please tell me what I was doing wrong when posting? I referenced a post made here on stack and also mentioned that I tried using built-in functions. Is it a case of not posting coding attempts? Thanks again!

Comment: @NiviM You're welcome. (I think you can improve your question with an attempt or two and describe what you don't understand/where you are stuck or if you think you used the wrong functions, just something like this to show your effort and work which you have done)