# Combine 2 PHP array into multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 separated arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Header 1
    [1] => Header 2
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Content #1
            [1] => Content #2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Content #1.1
        )

)
```

How to combine those 2 arrays into multidimensional with a format like this below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Header 1] => Content #1
            [Header 2] => Content #1.1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Header 1] => Content #2
        )

)
```

The purpose is to create HTML table. I found a way to create a table from here [How to create a HTML Table from a PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array) but the array format should be like the last one.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301378/combine-arrays-to-form-multidimensional-array-in-php ... check it

Comment: If you want to learn something you should modify the recipe you found to match the input data you have, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

A straight forward way using `foreach` loops...

```
$arr1 = ['Header 1', 'Header 2'];
$arr2 = [['Content #1', 'Content #2'],
    [ 'Content #1.1']];

$result= [];
foreach ( $arr2 as $arr3 ){
    $partial = [];
    foreach ( $arr3 as $key=>$value )  {
        $partial[$arr1[$key]] = $value;
    }
    $result[] = $partial;
}

print_r($result);
```

(Pleas excuse the not very inventive variable names)

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Header 1] => Content #1
            [Header 2] => Content #2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Header 1] => Content #1.1
        )

)
```

It could be simplified if you knew that the second array always had the same number of values as the first array as you could use `array_combine()` in the loop instead.  Although you could fudge this...

```
$arr1 = ['Header 1', 'Header 2'];
$arr2 = [['Content #1', 'Content #2'],
    [ 'Content #1.1']];

$result= [];
foreach ( $arr2 as $arr3 ){
    $arr4 = array_slice($arr1,0,count($arr3));
    $result[] = array_combine($arr4, $arr3);
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use the "+" operator i.e 
`$newArray = $array1 +array2`

Comment: Have you tried? It doesn't do anything near the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

**Input**

```
$array1 = array('Header 1','Header 2');
$array2 = array(array('Content #1','Content #2'),array('Content #1.1'));
```

**Solution**

```
$new = array();
foreach($array2 as $key => $row){
    for($i=1;$i<=count($row);$i++){
    $new[$key]['Header '.$i] = $row[$i-1];
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Header 1] => Content #1
            [Header 2] => Content #2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Header 1] => Content #1.1
        )

)
```